# Technical name for a "peculiar" use of switch statement: contains an if and for statement

Tags: c++

As a disclaimer, this is a homework problem. But it's one where the answer can't be found from our lecture notes and we're encouraged to find the answer through research (on the internet I presume). We're given the following code fragment, and asked for the technical name for this particular "peculiar" use of switch statement (this is in C++)

```
switch (x) {
   case 0:
      if ( m > n ) {
          case 1:
             for ( o = 0; o < 10; o += 1 ){
                case 2:
                   p += 1;
             }
      }
}
```

where x, m, n, o, and p are int

I've answered all of the questions given about how the code operates under different conditions, but I can not find this mysterious technical name for this kind of switch statement. I've tried a few creative google searches, and read several pages about switch statement, but can't find mention of a case like this where if and for are nested within. Can anyone point me in the right direction??

Comment: "goto in disguise" ;-) `case 2` is particularly insidious, since it jumps over the assignment to `o` - this would be ill-formed with a more usual loop like `for (int o = 0; o < 10; ++o)`.

Comment: In my opinion the technical name should be "coding styles to avoid".

Comment: It seems similar to Duffs device, but not quite.

Comment: Maybe there is something I am not seeing but how does the for loop terminate if o is never incremented?

Comment: @Dennis You should post that as the answer. I am pretty sure that this is what is being sought.

Comment: @Dennis: I'd say that Duff's device is the application of the same syntactic peculiarity used by this code ("case labels are just labels, they don't introduce a syntactic scope") to a particular task (loop unrolling). So it is similar, possibly even similar enough that whoever set the assignment is expecting that answer.

Comment: @GWW: since we don't see the definitions of the variables, and since this code is disturbing already, it might as well be because `int &p = o;` ;-)

Comment: @GWW : my bad, i typoed o as c in the incrementation.. i.e. c += 1 meant to be o += 1

but yeah i agree, they're probably looking for Duff's Device. Seems like kind of an obscure thing to ask us to find in an intro C++ course, no? Oh well! thanks all.

Answer (score 8):

A famous technique that is closely related to this is known as "Duff's Device". The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) page has a fairly detailed discussion that includes the following passage:

> C's default fall-through in case
>   statements has long been one of its
>   most controversial features; Duff
>   observed that "This code forms some
>   sort of argument in that debate, but
>   I'm not sure whether it's for or
>   against."

Comment: Note: There is another good, [related article here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html).

Comment: oops, in the for statement c is meant to be o, fixed it.

But yes, it does seem related to Duff's, thanks for pointing that  out I'll read up on that further!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if I've ever seen or heard of anything quite this twisted,
but I wonder if your prof wasn't thinking of Duff's device.  The
original version was:

```
register n=(count+7)/8;
switch(count%8){
case 0:     do{      *to = *from++;
case 7:              *to = *from++;
case 6:              *to = *from++;
case 5:              *to = *from++;
case 4:              *to = *from++;
case 3:              *to = *from++;
case 2:              *to = *from++;
case 1:              *to = *from++;
            }while(--n>0);
}
```

(`to` pointed to a memory mapped IO register.)  To quote Tom Duff (the
inventor), "I feel a combination of pride and revulsion at this
discovery," and "Many people (even bwk?) have said that the worst
feature of C is that switches don't break automatically before each case
label.  This code forms some sort of argument in that debate, but I'm
not sure whether it's for or against."

Many, many years ago (about the time Tom Duff invented this), I came up
with something along the lines of:

```
switch ( category[*p] ) {
//  ...
case CH_DOT:
    if ( category[*(p + 1)] == CH_DIGIT )
case CH_DIGIT:
        p = parseNumber( p );
    else
case CH_PUNCT:
        p = parsePunct( p );
    break;
//  ...
}
```

I never gave it a name, however, and never let it escape into production
code.